# List Google Plus pages managed by user

Tags: google-plus

I am building a tool to allow users to extract their Google Plus stream as RSS feed.
Unfortunately Google Plus API does not allow to get a list of Google Plus Pages managed by a user.
The tool is using OAuth 2 Authentication, and this allows to get Google ID of the currently logged in user. 
What Google API or APIs allows to get a list of of Google Plus Pages IDs managed by a user with a given Google ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of mid-Feb 2014 there is no way of getting list of Pages associated with Authenticated  Google Plus account. 
Acces to Pages API, that supposedely allows this functionality, is by whitelist only.